# kotlin equality test of nullable reference of int

Tags: kotlin

I do not understand this snippet of code I found on [the official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html):

```
fun main() {
    val a: Int = 100
    val boxedA: Int? = a
    val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a

    val b: Int = 100000
    val boxedB: Int? = b
    val anotherBoxedB: Int? = b

    println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // true
    println(boxedB === anotherBoxedB) // false
}
```

Why the equality changes when the variable's value change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM caches Integers for values between -128 and 127. Integers outside that range may or may not be cached - if they aren't, then each call to `Integer i = 128` will return a new object.

Kotlin inherits this behaviour (an `Int?` in kotlin is an `Integer` in Java).

So, back to your example:

- `100` gets cached, hence `boxedA` and `anotherBoxedA` are the same object
- but `100000` is not cached and 2 different instances of Integers are returned